# Inheritance in action method parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have the following classes:

```
class SomethingBase 
{
    public string SharedProperty { get; set; }
}

class ChildClassOne : SomethingBase 
{
    public string SpecificPropertyOne { get; set; }
}

class ChildClassTwo : SomethingBase 
{
    public string SpecificPropertyTwo { get; set; }
}
```

And I have ASP.NET MVC View which has two HTML-forms. These forms are calling the same action method.
This action method should receive any of two `SomethingBase` class derivatives.
However, if I create single parameter like `SomethingBase param`, then only the `SharedProperty` is received. This behavior can be explained by binding mechanism of ASP.NET MVC.

To make my action method work I created the next definition:

```
public ActionResult(ChildClassOne param1, ChildClassTwo param2)
```

`SharedProperty` goes to both params, but specific properties are populated only for object, which was actually passed from view. It works, but I don't think that this is the only solution.

Are there some best-practice solutions for this situation?

Comment: Does your method rely specifically on these properties?

Comment: This action method was split on two methods before. However SpecificProperty is actually multiple properties in the base class. There was a lot of code duplication in these action method, so I decided to combine them to one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `TryUpdateModel` of `Controller` class make it work. However, this way is not pretty elegant.

```
...
public ActionResult Save(FormCollection collection)
        {
            SomethingBase model = null;
            if (collection.AllKeys.Contains("SpecificOne"))
            {
                model = new ChildOne();
                TryUpdateModel<ChildOne>((ChildOne)model, collection);
            }
            else
            {
                model = new ChildTwo();
                TryUpdateModel<ChildTwo>((ChildTwo)model, collection);
            }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a view model for each action since they are not alike. There's really no reason to try to use a base class in this case.

Comment: Basically, I simplified the real case. There actually, are two separate PartialViews.

Comment: each view should have it's own view model

Comment: My two PartialViews have separate view models. They have same form, which calls single ActionMethod.